# How to handle status 302 redirect in c# httpwebreqest ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, httpwebrequest

Here is my code:

```
   @{
        //string postString = "parameter=value";
        const string contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://somehost:8080/myApp") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        webRequest.ContentType = contentType;
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        webRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postString);
        requestWriter.Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        string location = resp.Headers["Location"];
        Response.Redirect(location);
    }
```

response from `http://somehost:8080/myApp` is 302 redirect to some other domain. If I use `webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;` and write response (`Response.Write(StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd())`), resulting html is not shown correctly because resources with relative links could not be resolved.

So, I came up with this solution but I feel that it's not correct. It seems to me that my solution is sort of 'hackaround'.

Is there better solution?

Answer (score 0):

change your relative url into absolute

```
 url = objHttpWebResponse.Headers["Location"].ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show("Redirect To " + objHttpWebResponse.Headers["Location"]);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        Uri final = new Uri(new Uri(txtURL.Text), url);
                        string finalurl = final.AbsoluteUri;
                        download(finalurl);
```